# Searching for plain text file markup language with simple syntax

Tags: language, aptitude, markup

I prefer normal plain text files over OpenOffice files, because there are much smaller and the editing is faster. Most text editors open faster than OpenOffice or any other office application.

What I need:

- The "source" needs to be readable, with little overhead.
- It should be compilable in Linux/maven
- There should be a program (editor) with a design view -> executing the syntax

I was thinking something like apt [Doxia](http://maven.apache.org/doxia/index.html). I really like the syntax, but I do not want to run Maven or open Eclipe everytime I want to see the contend rendered (showing the tables, listings and so on)

In a perfect world I would use Notepad++ / scite(?) with a nice plugin to write apt files. Any ideas?

Comment: You want a editor for windows or linux ??

Comment: @subanki: No, a markup language.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[ReST](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ReStructuredText) and [Markdown](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markdown) are easy to write, but I've not seen WYSIWYG editors for them.

Comment: They both look interesting. I think I will have to choose between apt and the two you recommended. Need some time to evaluate them. Thx for the help.
It seems like there is no good lightweight wysiwyg editor for such compact languages. Too bad.

Comment: FYI, SuperUser itself uses Markdown in questions and answers.

Answer (score 0):

HTML.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
</head>

<p>Hi there!</p>
```